# In Godot How to Change Cell Fractured Cube behavior from blender which is imported with suffix -rigid to STATIC during runtime

Tags: static, runtime, game-physics, godot, rigid-bodies

> Hello I have imported a cell fractured cube from blender which uses
> -rigid as suffix so its a rigidbody by default but I am trying to change it to static during runtime and via some code,  my godot
> understanding level can be consider absolute newbie / beginner any
> help will be a blessing : ).
>
> Follwing is a still frame of cell fractured cube imported with suffix
> -rigid and you can see the object is falling and breaking and i want to change this behaviour to static during runtime via code, and
> `Rigidbody.MODE_STATIC` is doing nothing while `mode = Rigidbody.MODE_STATIC`
> is not working either but throwing error stating 'mode' is not declared
> in the current scope

[image]

Comment: On which node will you attach the script that want to make this change, and where is the rigid body relative to it?

Comment: the -rigid suffix in blender has made godot to auto apply the rigidbody to all the fractured objects and placed it in a spatial node named CrackedUvCube which is also the name of the blender file. All this process was automative so when i double clicked on the CrackedUvCube.gd file it instantianted a CrackedUvCube.tscn so i saved it and added a camera to it and when I hit play this scene it runs fine but i am trying to change it to static so that the cube dont break unless i told it to. Rest is explained in the question. I attaching the script to the CrackedUvCube.tscn

Comment: No, not everything is there. And your comment didn't answer my question. You say in your question that you tried `mode = Rigidbody.MODE_STATIC` but it gave you an error. Which tells me that you have a script where you were doing it. I don't know where is the script relative to the rigid body, I just know it isn't on it, because that should have worked. So you need to get a reference to the rigid body from the script so it can manipulate it. How to get a reference is very common and general issue. Most common solutions are using NodePath export or using $ expression. Edit: assuming Godot 3.x.

Comment: thanks for giving me your time i know i am doing something absolutely stupid here. Soon i will upload a short  few seconds clip of my whole ordeal from blender to godot and its not that big i will be able to show it in just few second and hope you or someone else will be able to help, till then Again thanks for providing the info really appreciate that.